# Can an object track its references?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

I'm working on python3. I've encountered a strange situation which can only be explained if an object has a way to tell if there are any references to it. However, this behaviour doesn't seem to affect python2.7. I've already discarded the explanation of it being a garbage collection issue, since `gc.disable()` makes no difference. Just to clarify, this is not a problem for me, but I'd really like to know what the heck is going on.

---

If you are interested on the particular situation, here comes a MWE.

I'm working with this code snipped from the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/timers.html) (matplotlib 2.0.0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def update_title(axes):
    axes.set_title(datetime.now())
    axes.figure.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(-3, 3)
ax.plot(x, x*x)
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100)
timer.add_callback(update_title, ax)
timer.start()
#timer_another_ref = timer
#timer = None
plt.show()
```

Now, if I uncomment the line `timer = None`, the timer doesn't work anymore (only in python3, as I said previously). On the other hand, if I now uncomment the other line, it works as expected.

---

As a sidenote, I have two computers. One is running python 3.4.3 on ubuntu 14.04 and using the backend Qt5Agg, and the other is running python 3.5.2 on ubuntu 16.04 and using the backend TkAgg. This behaviour is only observed on the former (I'd guess it's related to the backend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the reference count of an object, then you can use:

```
sys.getrefcount(something)
```

Note that the following would output `2` because there's a temporary reference to the list.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(sys.getrefcount(lst))
```

Comment: So, in this case, the timer may be checking for sys.getrefcount(self). Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it (almost certainly) is due to garbage collection.  In CPython, the vast bulk of garbage collection is done by reference counting, which has nothing to do with the `gc` module.  `gc` is only needed to collect trash in reference *cycles*, in which cases reference counting alone is helpless.  Example:

```
class T:
    def __del__(self):
        print("going away")

t = T()
print("before")
t = None  # remove only reference to the object
print("after")
```

Under every version of CPython ever released (even those before `gc` existed), that prints:

```
before
going away
after
```

Now get fancier:

```
x = T()
y = T()
x.ref = y
y.ref = x
print("before")
x, y = None, None
print("after")

import gc
gc.collect()
print("after gc")
```

There `x` refers to `y`, and vice versa.  It's "a cycle".  Each is reachable from the other, so their reference counts can never fall below 1 (unless `x.ref` and/or `y.ref` is rebound too).  So under all version of CPython, that prints:

```
before
after
```

at first.  Under Python 3, it goes on to print:

```
going away
going away
after gc
```

but under Python 2 it only goes on to print:

```
after gc
```

That's due to an obscure technical problem with cyclic trash containing objects with `__del__` methods; Python 2 can't reclaim them, but Python 3 can.

Alas, it's not possible for me to guess exactly what's happening in your example.  That requires studying the source code for `fig.canvas.new_timer` under the two implementations.

But the bottom line is clear enough:  if you need an object to stay alive, make sure it's reachable from your code.  After it becomes unreachable, one garbage collection subsytem or another is free to destroy it at any time.

Comment: I'd always thought that ``gc.disable()`` prevented garbage collection altogether. So there are TWO garbage collectors, and ``gc.disable()``  just stops one of them.

Comment: In CPython (the C implementation of Python), that's true.  The reference-counting (RC) system is fundamental, and cannot be turned off - Python programs typically create new objects at a ferocious rate, and without the RC system most programs would quickly run out of memory.  The distinct `gc` system is used _only_ to reclaim garbage in cycles (the RC system is too weak to identify them).